# RPC crashing Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rpc

I'm experiencing a certainly disturbing issue in the last hours.
It appears that every RPC call I do using an array (int, float, byte, etc) is crashing the whole engine.
I've made a little working example of how to reproduce, and I would like to know if it's certainly a bug, or if im doing something very wrong:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Network.InitializeServer(4, 25000, true);
        networkView.RPC("test", RPCMode.All, new float[5]);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
    }

    [RPC]
    void test(float[] lol){
        Debug.Log("received "+lol);
    }
}
```

Using only this script in a Camera with a network view is enough to get the thing crashed. Did I do something wrong??
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I was having the same problem for one whole day, I even formatted my PC and it still crashed.
Finally I realized I have upgrade Unity in the past day, and it should be the culprit. After downgrading back to 4.6.1f, it works well!
Then I try to find anyone having the same problem, apparently you are the only one who posted this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bug in 4.6.3 and 4.6.4 when i try to send a bytearray over an rpc in unity5 it does the job. Hope it helped

Answer (score 0):

Using RPC call in Unity is [restricted to certain types of parameters](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/net-RPCDetails.html):

> You can use the following variable types as parameters to RPCs:-
>   int float string NetworkPlayer NetworkViewID Vector3 Quaternion

So what you can do instead is serialize/convert the array to a string, and then back to array on the other side.

Comment: Agreed, but when you try to send data it's not supported, we get this error:
"Sending RPC failed because 'teste' parameter 0 (UnityEngine.GameObject) is not supported." and not a total crash.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [OnServerInitialized](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Network.OnServerInitialized.html) function to your class. And after that you can use  `networkView.RPC("test", RPCMode.All, new float[5]);` in this function.

And also i can't see NetworkView instance in your class.

Like

```
public NetworkView networkView;
void OnServerInitialized(){
    Debug.Log("Server initialized and ready");
    networkView.RPC("test", RPCMode.All, new float[5]);
}
```

Comment: It changed nothing. Still crashing.

Comment: Do you have networkView instance? Maybe you get null.

Comment: Yeah. When I dont, or i'm not connected, Unity throws a "Cant send RPC w/o networkview connected" or something like that.

Comment: Please send error message in console. It's strange. If unity totaly crash before sending error. Maybe your project has strange problem.

Comment: There's no error in console, with that script, in the moment I press "run", it crashes instantaneously.

Comment: please try RPCMode.Others for RPC Mode. If your code has rpc calls recursively it crashes Unity suddenly.

Comment: Still gettin a crash. I'm suspecting it might be a bug.